# Set WebPartZone Title in SharePoint 2013 Snippet

Tags: 2013, web-part, page-layout, web-part-zone

Does anyone know the right way to give a web part zone (inside a SP2013 HTML Page Layout) a nice human readable title?

I used the following snippet:

```
<div data-name="WebPartZone">
    <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <div xmlns:ie="ie">
        <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" DisplayTitle="Sidebar" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="x9f20386d0c5648cc8fca09e815f2a754" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
            <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
            <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
        <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
    </div>
    <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
</div>
```

As you see, I tried setting title with property `DisplayTitle` to "Sidebar" but it doesn't work. It just renders the titles on the page like this: Zone 1, Zone 2, ...

Isn't this the correct property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use "Title", as shown below.

```
<!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Sidebar" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="x9f20386d0c5648cc8fca09e815f2a754" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
```